# How to display information from MySQL in a textbox?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, combobox, textbox

I an new in creating programs in Visual Studio C#. I want to create a program that reads the information from MySQL and display the selected information in a textbox. What I have here is a code for displaying the information in a combobox.

This is the code to display information from MySQL in a combobox:

```
private void comboBoxDistrict_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBoxDistrictName.Items.Clear();
        string query = "SELECT employee_lastname, employee_firstname, employee_middlename FROM employee WHERE employee_district = '" + comboBoxDistrict.Text.ToString() + "'";
        DBConn db = new DBConn();
        DataTable tbl = db.retrieveRecord(query);
        foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
        comboBoxDistrictName.Items.Add(row[0].ToString() + ", " + row[1].ToString() + " " + row[2].ToString());
    }
```

What I need is to display the information in a textbox. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: you should used **DataBindings**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Change the assign from your `ComboBox` to be your `textBox`

```
txtBox1.Text = row[0].ToString() + ", " + row[1].ToString() + " " + row[2].ToString());
```

You may take care of iteration, since just last row in this case will be shown in the `textBox`

Answer (score 0):

Use StringBuilder for performance reasons and to get around the "problem" of just the last row showing up in your TextBox as in Rami's example:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
{
    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}, {1} {2}",
                                row[0].ToString(),
                                row[1].ToString(),
                                row[2].ToString()));
}

txtBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

or simply append the next row to the TextBox using "+=":

```
txtBox1.Text += row[0].ToString() + ", " +
                row[1].ToString() + " " +
                row[2].ToString()) + "\r\n";
```